# How is art critical of life after modernity has ended?

Tags: postmodernism, art, modernism, modernity, utopia

Assuming valuable art is still being made, given it can no longer voice [modernity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modernity) except in a pastiche and irrelevance, in what way can it be ***utopian***: by which I just mean capable of being read as a criticism of the rest of life?

Comment: What constitutes 'critically important art'? Why might it cease being possible after 'modernity' has ended? What is your definition of modernity? Why would it be 'utopian' necessarily? Adding this info to your question might improve it.

Comment: those are difficultr questions @Futilitarian !

Comment: idk this isn't the place to argue that art or philosophy is necessarily utopian in scope or the relation with modern, as opposed to post-modern, philosophy and society @Futilitarian if you ask just one thing to make the question more answerable, what would it be?

Comment: I guess I would ask for the definition of terms, so that responses are informed by a context that matches your intent.

Comment: of 'utopian' or also 'art' 'voice' 'modernity' 'important' @Futilitarian ?

Comment: i am not sure that will be any clearer @Futilitarian ?

Comment: Essentially, I think your question needs to be a lot longer; that you need to put more effort into describing what you mean. Your adding of the modernity link helps, but my first comment still stands.

Comment: that i need to argue for a question @Futilitarian ?

Comment: Nailing the word 'modern' (which means: "the present time" ) to a time in the past is so absurd and ridiculous as to render invalid any statements about it. Get a correct name for the time period and I'll think about it.

Answer (score 1):

Art as social criticism continues to have impact and efficacy, I would argue. For example:

- Kehinde Wiley's work is a critique of how Black people are undervalued. It operates by transposing ordinary Black subjects, typically from lower socioeconomic backgrounds, into the elevated settings of the classical art tradition. https://www.columbusmakesart.com/place/8961-portrait-of-andries-stilte-ii
- Much of Banksy's work operates as social commentary. For instance, the mural on the wall separating off the Palestanian community that depicts a portal to a tropical paradise, https://banksyexplained.com/the-segregation-wall-palestine-2005/, where the glimpse of utopian freedom highlights the underlying oppressiveness of the wall.
- Marina Abramović's famous "The Artist is Present" can be read as a statement about the continuing importance of direct, immediate, human contact even in a depersonalized technological world. https://www.moma.org/calendar/exhibitions/964

It's true that one cannot trace a single coherent philosophical message in contemporary art. But that speaks more to the incoherency of contemporary philosophy than to any deficiency in art.

Comment: I think people criticise things that are salient for them. We don't all live in the same circumstances, and everything can't be salient.